# EnteriseLibrary 6 and Sqlite, impossible?

Tags: .net, sqlite, enterprise-library

In Enterpriselibrary 6, I configure the engine database in .config file lo use Log engine and Exception Handling; ok i can successful attach the provider to my db file, and i can create a context of sqlite under the database apis of enterprise library (and i can use queries, inserts, via command), but i can't see the logs and exceptions log in this database,

I search for more info and i can see that sqlite can't add procedures in .net version (only a special version can do it), the enterprise library need a db with the tables and procedures necessaries to work (for sql server a .sql file is provided); i can see than a old version (and version 5 too) can work, i see a demonstration of config http://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SQLiteDataProvider41
but not is complete (providerMappings is not necessary now, the provider must insert in System.Data section), no has examples
my question: how i can do? any way to do work in EL6?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a fully functional example with the necessary provider & FormattedDatabaseTraceListener, to make run! 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/657233/Enterprise-Library-6-Sqlite-Logging-and-Exceptions